# How to set the default date of multiple bootstrap Ddatepickers

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a dynamically generated table of inputs, the first column of which is a date field. I am using this [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for this. Each input works fine because I name them individually in the following loop

```
for ($r= 1; $r <= $rows; $r++) { 
  $thisDate = '"'.'date'.$r.'"';
     ...
        <input class="datepicker" name= <?php Echo $thisDate; ?> >
     ...
}
```

[image]

However, as you can see in the image, only the first item sets a default value

**How can I get them all to set a default date?**

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    "setDate": new Date(),
    todayBtn: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "top"                  
  }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery each() method to set default value to all datepickers.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.datepicker').each(function () {
        $(this).datepicker({
            "setDate": new Date(),
            todayBtn: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
            orientation: "top"
        }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to set the desired value on the inputs before calling the datepicker init:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oToday = new Date();
    var sToday = oToday.getMonth()+1 + "/" + oToday.getDate() + "/" + oToday.getFullYear();
    $('.datepicker').prop("value", sToday).datepicker({
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

The above still requires some tweaking for the dates to be in the exact same format, but it was meant as a gist. The same in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tuG6C/929/